# Can we call action:support for a vf component called in a vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have this below vf component called in vf page -

```
<c:AutoComplete allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="Product2" valueField="Id" targetField="{!wrapper.targetField}" style="width:200px"/>
```

Can we have a action:support called on change of the values for targetField.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The component can call any js on the parent page. Simply call it like you always do.

If actionfunction on parent is named `myFunction` then just use `myFunction();`

I have used attributes to set the name of function to call as well to make it more componety then used `window["attrName"]` to check if function is there and call it but if you do not need the flexibility just call as usual and expect it to be there

Comment: Hi Eric. I am unable to follow u. Can u share me some example..